# Transaction Commit and Rollback with Static DB Connection c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcplistener

Currently I am working on C# project which is basically a TCP/Socket based server which runs at dedicated IP and Port. This server may receive 1000 requests per second and every request requires a number of SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT queries to be run in Oracle DB. So to handle the situation amicably I have done following:

1. Made it multi-threaded (every request is being entertained in a separate thread)
2. To improve the performance I open connection at start of server and assign it to static variable to use it for every thread to perform DB activities so every thread doesn't require overhead of opening and closing connection.

The above two steps improved server response time tremendously.

**Challenge/Problem:**
Since every thread performs many DB UPDATE / INSERT so to maintain data integrity these activities must be in transaction scope.

I tried System.Transaction.TransactionScope() in thread but it is not working at all and all insert/update queries are being committed before calling scope.complete() (Not sure but may be due to already opened DB connection at start of server in other words, DB connection is opened before starting TransactionScope())

I also tried StaticDBConnection.BeginTransaction(.....) in the thread but since connection is static so it is impacting other threads too.

**Question:**
Is there any way to use Begin/Commit transaction with static DB connection or I have to withdraw from the idea of opening connection at beginning of server start which obviously will badly impact the performance as 1000 times per second connection will be opened and closed.

**Your expert opinion will be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to work (correctly) this way - you need to use separate connection for each thread. `SqlConnection` is not designed to be used by multiple threads.

But that doesn't mean 1000 connections per second will always be opened. Because of connection pooling, as soon as you are done with connection (by calling `Close` or `Dispose`) - connection is returned to the pool and next time you call `Open` - connection from the pool (if available) will be used instead of really opening new connection to database.

For example, if database work for one request takes 10 ms - ~100 requests per second can be handled by the same "physical" database connection. All you need to do for this is just creating new `SqlConnection`, opening it, then closing when done, as usual (and ensuring that connection pooling is not disabled and max pool size is appropriate for your task).

With such high request rate you can also benefit from asynchronous processing. Socket can accept and handle incoming requests in asynchronous way, and database work can also be performed asynchronously. This will reduce number of threads in use and will improve perfomance, because creating and maintaining threads is also not free. By processing request asynchronously - thread is freed and returned to another pool (.NET thread pool) during IO operations (such as waiting for request on socket, or performing database query) and so number of "busy" threads (and total threads) is much less than if you will use new thread for every socket connection.

Comment: Thanks Evk for your quick and adequate reply.